# Numpy Filling in Consecutive Values in 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two lists `a=[2,4,9]`, and `b=[1,3,7]`. These are scientific observations and I need array `c = [[2 1],[3 0],[4 3],[5 0],[6 0],[7 5]]`.
Basically I need to fill in zeros between the observation times. I have this hacky loop way, but is there's a faster, neater vectorization way?

```
    a = np.array(a).reshape((-1, 1))
    b = np.array(b).reshape((-1, 1))
    mat = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
    xx = np.arange(np.min(a), np.max(a))
    c = np.zeros((xx.shape[0],2))
    c[:,0] = xx
    for i in range(len(a)):
        idx = np.where(xx==a[i])[0]
        c[idx,1] = b[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing what you're trying to do correctly, you could build the two column separately (one for the "times" and one with the values at the proper indexes), then concatenate them to form a 2D matrix:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,4,9])
b = np.array([1,3,7])

t0 = min(a)                       # first "time"
c0 = np.arange(t0,max(a)+1)       # range of "times"
c1 = np.zeros(c0.size)            # value column
c1[a-t0] = b                      # assign values
c  = np.stack((c0,c1)).T          # assemble

print(c)

[[2. 1.]
 [3. 0.]
 [4. 3.]
 [5. 0.]
 [6. 0.]
 [7. 0.]
 [8. 0.]
 [9. 7.]]
```

Comment: This is the line I was looking for: `c1[a-t0] = b` Why does that work the way it does?

Comment: It offsets the times back so that the first time corresponds to index 0 and all subsequent times are shifted back by the same amount, placing the values at indexes positioned relative to zero.